# A particle is moving in a straight line with velocity v m.s⁻¹

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Question

[image]

My Attempt

[image]

I have done part A and got it right, but am struggling with part B. I have attached my attempt on the question as well as the full question.

The correct answer for part B is:
t1 = 4.07 s  or  t2 = 7.93 s (5 marks)

But I'm not sure where I went wrong and what I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula 1) for the position is fine, but it is valid only up to $t=4$. Hence your solution $t=4.065$ must be discarded.

Your formula 2) isn't correct, because position $s(t)$ at $t=4$ is $8/15$: a constant must then be added to account for that. The correct formula is as follows:
$$
s(t)=\int_0^t v(\tau)\,d\tau=
\int_0^4 (\tau^2-0.4\tau-4.4)\,d\tau+
\int_4^t (30-5\tau)\,d\tau=30t-{5\over2}t^2-80+{8\over15}.
$$

Comment: Where does it say that, at t=4 is 10?

Comment: @KurosakiIchigo That's a consequence of your formula 1), just substitute $t=4$.

Comment: @KurosakiIchigo Sorry, I miscomputed $s(4)$, it was $8/15$, not $10$. I corrected and added some more explanation.